# How to run apache-flink 1.6.2 in localhost?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I installed `apache-flink` (1.6.2) using [Apache’s Flink quick start tutorial](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/quickstart/setup_quickstart.html). Actually I installed it using this command:

```
brew install apache-flink
```

Now, I want to run `flink` in my localhost (More precisely: http://localhost:8081). But I couldn't find `start-local.sh` or `start-cluster.sh` in the `bin` folder.

Answer (score 3):

Homebrew installs packages in the Cellar.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/
```

If you missed the output when installing the package, you can find the path to an package post-installation with `brew info`. Running `brew info apache-flink` will return a path such as the following, which will depend on the version of Flink you have installed.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-flink/1.6.2/
```

The full path to the start-local.sh will therefore be:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-flink/1.6.2/libexec/bin/start-local.sh
```